# Matlab: How can I find the number of black pixels in a color image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I wish to find the number of black pixels in a color image using MATLAB, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `nnz` like this -

```
nnz(all(im==0,3))
```

where `im` is your image data.

Alternatives - `sum(reshape(all(im==0,3),[],1))` and `sum(sum(all(im==0,3)))`.

The assumption here is that black pixels are triplets `(0,0,0)`.

---

Instead if you define black pixels as pixels that have values in the interval `[0 th]` for the same pixel location across all channels, use this -

```
nnz(all(im<=th,3))
```

Comment: Taking care, of course, that your definition of `black` is that all RGB values are exactly `0`, that near-blacks such as `1,1,1` (I'm assuming a scale `[0..255]`) are not black.

Comment: I am a bit lost. If my im is <1536x2048x3 uint8> does the assumption that black pixels are (0,0,0) is correct?

Comment: @user2916044 That's right! That is all three - R,G and B has to be zero for the same pixel to be counted in. Weren't you looking for such a thing?

Comment: @user2916044 the assumption is that by black you mean pure black, and not an extremely dark colour that would look black to a human.

Comment: @user2916044 If there's any other criteria to define your "black" pixels, let us know.

Comment: One suggestion that I would make is to perhaps convert the image into grayscale, then threshold by a relatively low number (like 10 or something), then count the number of pixels that are black.  Intensities from 0 to a small range concentrated around there perceptually looks like they're black, even though the intensities may be non-zero.  However, if you're looking for pure black, then comparing to the tuple of `(0,0,0)` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @rayryeng I think it's a good assumption on the requirements of the problem, but I would still wait for OP to confirm the definition of "black" pixels according to his/her requirements.

Comment: @rayryeng BTW that don't let that stop yourself posting an answer there, maybe OP is looking for such a count of black pixels.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I mean pure black but I like the threshold by a relatively low number idea. The problem that thresholding might cause changes the image.

Comment: @user2916044 Not sure what you meant by "changes the image". We are only getting the count of "black pixels, so the image remains the same. Could you elaborate on that. Also, for the thresholding, would you like to have one threshold across all the three channels (R,G,B) of the image or three different thresholds for the 3 channels or one grayscale threshold after converting the colored image to grayscale one?

Comment: tresholding a grayscale image will remove some things. I was not thinking about a color image.

Comment: @user2916044 Okay, so the remaining options are - `one threshold across all the three channels (R,G,B) of the image or three different thresholds for the 3 channels`. What do you propose?

Comment: I think that one threshold across all the three channels (R,G,B) will be interesting.

Comment: @user2916044 For that, the change would be minimal. The code would be - `nnz(all(im<=th,3))`, where `th` is the threshold.